# HTML5 video stuck on Chrome, works fine on IE

Tags: google-chrome, video, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video

Streaming a MP4 video from a remote site to Chrome using `<video>` element, works great on IE - but on Google Chrome, the videos buffering is **extremely slow** (1st second buffers for 5 seconds, then plays this second, then 5 seconds to buffer the 2nd second etc.).

- The videos format is MP4 with H264 encoding.
- This does **not** happen on all clients (though I failed to find a common attribute which can cause this).

Any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Can you do a packet capture with Wireshark or similar and post a link to it?  Let's see what's going on over the wire.

Comment: @Brad This happens only on some of my client's (customers) computers. Restarting, Updating to latest chrome version - does not help. The strange thing is that using IE they do not experience this problem and the video plays smoothly.

Comment: All of that information isn't relevant without not being able to see what's actually happening.  It's not strange at all that a different browser with completely different optimizations, different media player with different codecs, different buffering, etc., would perform differently.  Chrome does a lot of hacky stuff when fetching media data.  Your MP4 probably doesn't have its moov atom at the beginning.  Your server might not be supporting range requests.  Who knows though, as your question provides almost no information.  A packet capture, profiling snapshot, something would be useful.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your comments. Regarding range requests - the server does support them otherwize this will happen on all clients. Same goes for the moov atom. Without developer access to the problematic browsers, which information do you think is relevant and accessable for me to provide ?

Comment: You could take a packet capture server-side, and filter out data to just one of the clients that's causing you trouble.  You could use Weinre to remote debug.  You could also log all of the MediaStream events and statuses, and compare them to a working client to see what the difference is.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. This is a bug with Chrome 58, as everything was working in previous versions of Chrome. Chrome 58 does not play files unless the Metadata is formatted. You can run your files through ffmpeg using "-movflags faststart" and Chrome will play the files just fine.

Comment: @guyfromfargo thank you so much. but I solved the issue by changing the birate.

Comment: Same problem here, starting with Chrome 58 as well on all platforms. Its <video> element just gets stuck on all our mp4 files. Works fine in all other browsers... :/

Comment: @BjornW Please see the answer I just posted, I was able to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @KobyDouek for the heads-up. However transcoding all our millions of mp4 files is not an option, and it's really strange if Chrome suddenly would break mp4/h264/avc support completely (although I've heard they've threatened to completely remove h264 at some point). I need to dig up why Chrome fails with these videos I guess, and I'm sure there are many different cases and reasons it can fail.

Comment: @BjornW Chrome will not stop supporting h264 videos, but it has very bad performance with **high bitrate** videos. That is the issue, and that is how I reloved it.

Comment: @KobyDouek Maybe, but this has been working flawlessly for 2 years in our entire setup, and just suddenly stopped working about 4-6 weeks ago when Chrome did some release then. That is very strange..

Comment: @BjornW Same here. Version 56 and forward have this issue. I posted a bug, let's hope for the best. It took me many days to understand this is a bitrate issue. I hope you find your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self-solved this issue by changing the video's bitrate to a lower value (276k).